# setting date.timezone php 56 Yosemite

Tags: php, date, datetime

I'm following a Lynda.com training for PHP and I've Apache2 with PHP 5.6 installed. I work on a macbook air with OS X Yosemite 10.10.4 installed. My problem is that I can't get the timezone right.

When i load `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`
I get the message: *Warning: phpinfo(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone. in /Users/user/Sites/my_phpinfo.php on line 1*

I have doublechecked `/usr/local/etc/php/5.6/php.ini` and the timezone I add is `date.timezone = "Europe/Amsterdam"`

Following to the course I have to edit the additional ini file because it overwrite the loaded configuration file. The only additional configuration file I got is `/usr/local/etc/php/5.6/conf.d/ext-intl.ini`

In this file there is no `date.timezone` at all. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is stopping you from just adding it to that file?

Comment: phpinfo() tells you what .ini file(s) it used. make sure you're changing the correct .ini, and make sure you restart apache after changing the file...

Comment: I did, I paste 'date.timezone = "Europe/Amsterdam"' into 'ext-intl.ini' and restart apache2. No difference. I've checked, the loaded config file = /usr/local/etc/php/5.6/php.ini the loaded additional config file = /usr/local/etc/php/5.6/conf.d/ext-intl.ini

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting it manually at the beginning of your PHP code?

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Amsterdam');
...
```

Comment: Thanks, thats the solution. I had tried but the same way as in the .ini file: date.timezone = "Europe/Amsterdam" No error anymore, the only thing: under Directive => is local and master no value.